# Basic arrays copy OpenCL GPU

Tags: arrays, c, optimization, gpu, opencl

Can someone help me to figure out of to traslate this C code for CPU, to kernel code for GPU

```
int a[N], b[N];
b[0] = a[0];
b[N] = a[N];

for (i=1; i<N-1; i++) 
    b[i]= a[i-1] + a[i] + a[i+1];
```

I thought about writing it this way, but I would like to find a better performing solution

```
__kernel void adjacentCopy(__global double *a, __global double *b, const unsigned int n) {

    int gid = get_global_id(0);

    if (gid < N) 
        b[gid] = a[gid-1]+a[gid]+a[gid+1];
    
}
    // and than execute the two base case into the host
```

Anyone can suggest a way to organize the code to use local memory, and also bringing back the two extremes cases into the kernel, without adding branches divergence

Comment: Regarding the input code, it looks like the array is small (because of a limited stack size). Note the values are left uninitialized so there is an undefined behaviour and `b[0] = b[0]; a[N] = a[N];` is completely useless. In fact, `a[N] = a[N];` cause another undefined behaviour... The computation is too cheap for GPU to be really useful and the latency of data transfer and the speed of data transfer will certainly cause the computation to be slower on GPU. Put it shortly: your input code is bogus and using GPU is useless here.

Comment: Hi, thanks you for the reply, This code is just a concept to understand how to work efficiently on gpu

Comment: *i corrected the two base cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `kernel` in essence is a `for`-loop, of which every iteration runs in parallel. The exact order of execution is random, so there must not be any data dependencies from one iteration to the next; otherwise you have to use a double buffer (only read from one buffer and only write to the other).

In your case, the kernel would read:

```c
__kernel void adjacentCopy(const __global double *a, __global double *b, const unsigned int N) {
    int gid = get_global_id(0);
    if(gid==0||gid==N-1) return; // guard clause: do not execute the first and last element
    b[gid] = a[gid-1]+a[gid]+a[gid+1]; // double buffers to resolve data dependencies: only read from a and only write to b
}
```

With the extreme cases `gid==0||gid==N-1`, on such a computational grid you typically use periodic boundary conditions. Then the kernel would become branchless and look like this:

```c
__kernel void adjacentCopy(const __global double *a, __global double *b, const unsigned int N) {
    int gid = get_global_id(0);
    b[gid] = a[(gid+N-1)%N]+a[gid]+a[(gid+1)%N]; // periodic boundaries with modulo; in "(gid+N-1)" the "+N" ensures that the argument of the modulo operator always is positive
}
```

Now for the `local` memory optimization: Without it, for every thread, you read 3 neighboring values of `a` from slow `global` memory. In theory, you could only load one element per thread from `global` memory and use fast `local` memory to share the data within the workgroup. But the two threads at `gid==0||gid==N-1` will have to load 2 values from `global` memory, introducing branching, and this will likely kill any potential gain in performance. The added complication, together with no significant gains in performance, make the `local` memory optimization an unfavourable choice in this case. This is how the kernel would look like:

```c
#define def_workgroup_size 128 // set this to the size of the workgroup
__kernel void adjacentCopy(const __global double *a, __global double *b, const unsigned int N) {
    int gid = get_global_id(0);
    int lid = get_local_id(0);
    __local double cached_a[def_workgroup_size+2]; // as large as the workgroup, plus neighbors on the left and right sides of the workgroup
    if(lid==0) cached_a[lid] = a[(gid+N-1)%N]; // first thread in workgroup also has to load left neighbor
    cached_a[lid+1] = a[gid];
    if(lid==def_workgroup_size-1) cached_a[lid+1] = a[(gid+1)%N]; // last thread in workgroup also has to load right neighbor
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE); // barrier to make sure cached_a is entirely filled up
    b[gid] = cached_a[lid]+cached_a[lid+1]+cached_a[lid+2]; // read 3 values from local memory
}
```