# OpenCL Kernel and traditional loops

Tags: gpu, opencl, nvidia, amd-gpu

I'm studying OpenCL and I don't understand the relationship between traditional loop in a C/C++ code and kernel code.
Just for be clear a situation like that:

[image: Example]

So my question is: In the traditional loops I have `n` variable as my boundary while in kernel code I don't have it but I have `get_global_id(0)` that indicates the memory scope of my array, this means that I start from 0, and iterate until `get_global_id` matches with the maximum size of the array, `n` in this case? Or is something different?

Because in this other example I don't know how to write the correspond kernel code

[image: Example2]

I hope my question is clear because I'm not very well in English, sorry.

Thanks in advance for the help, if there are problems let me know!

Answer (score 2):

An OpenCL kernel is coded like a single iteration of a for-loop, but all iterations are run in parallel with random order.

Consider this vector addition example in C++, where for `i=0..N-1`, you add each element of the vectors one after the other:

```c
for(int i=0; i<N; i++) { // loop index i
    C[i] = A[i]+B[i]; // compute one after the other
}
```

In OpenCL, the vector addition looks like the inside of this for-loop, but as a function with the `kernel` keyword and all vectors as parameters:

```c
kernel void add_kernel(const global float* A, const global float* B, global float* C) {
    const int i = get_global_id(0);
    C[i] = A[i]+B[i]; // compute all loop indices i in parallel
}
```

You might be wondering: Where is `N`? You give `N` to the kernel on the C++ side as its "global range", so the kernel knows how much elements `i` to calculate in parallel.

Because in the OpenCL kernel every iteration runs in parallel, there must not be any data dependencies from one iteration to the next; otherwise you have to use a double buffer (only read from one buffer and only write to the other). In your second example with `A[i] = B[i-1]+B[i]+B[i+1]` you do exactly that: only read from `B`, only write to `A`. The implementation with periodic boundaries can be done branch-less, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72748813/9178992).

Comment: You're answer is absolutely clear! So for my second example I can do the same thing in your add_kernel code because I give n-1 to the kernel on the C++ side and I can do the operation of my loop in a simplest way on the kernel code like this: const int i=get_global_id(0) A[i]=b[i-1]+b[i]+b[i+1], right this?

Comment: Ok, I see your reference and is clear because is the same example as mine, thanks